# A soft question about the differene between guassian distribution and uniform distribution over a circle

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Choosing $n$ independently and uniformly distributed points from a unit circle is relatively easy and there are many ways to do it. One way for instance is the rejection method; choosing points in the circumscribing square and rejecting those that fall outside the circle. Another way is to use the pdf of the radial distance  $r$ of a random point and the angle $\theta$,and using $x=\sqrt{r} \cos \theta ,y=\sqrt{r} \sin \theta$, giving the point $(x,y)$.

The following picture depicts some uniformly and randomly chosen points in a unit circle.

[image]

What I  am confused about is how does the distribution of  independently and Gaussian distributed points over the same  circle look like and by what process /algorihtm do we chose them. Thanks for any responses\suggestions\insights.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the uniform distribution over the circle and pretty much any other non-uniform distribution is the lack of uniqueness.

If you say that the sequence of random points $X$ follow a uniform distribution over the circle $C$, then you are saying something very specific:

$$\forall A \subset C: P(X \in A) = \frac{\text{Area}(A)}{\text{Area}(C)}$$

We lose this nice uniqueness when we go to other distributions. In your gaussian example, it's not clear in what sense points are gaussian distributed since $C$ is bounded but the gaussian is unbounded.

We could say that we are assuming the bivariate gaussian to have its mean at the center of $C$. [Then we could say](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Cumulative_function_n_dimensional_Gaussians_12.2013.pdf):

$$P(|X| \leq r) \propto 1-e^{-r^2/2}$$
where $r$ is the [Mahalanobis distnce](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a2/Cumulative_function_n_dimensional_Gaussians_12.2013.pdf).

You can use acceptance/rejection here as well -- nothing special about Gaussian.